# hline plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy

My data points go like x = 1 to 10 and y = 0 to 1 and an array of 1000 points each.

```
>> array([[0.00000e+00, 1.00000e+00],
   [1.00000e-02, 9.79893e-01],
   [2.00000e-02, 9.21879e-01],
   ...,
   [9.99000e+00, 2.15619e-01],
   [1.00000e+01, 2.15619e-01],
   [1.00100e+01, 2.15618e-01]])
```

I  have calculated the half-width from `scipy.signal` for the y value and it looks like the below

```
>> (array([0.395881 , 0.324863 , 0.3012635, 0.283398 , 0.269297 , 0.2587625]),
    array([ 14.74704647,  33.76801591,  52.65272424,  71.46096096,
            90.27218935, 109.05898876]),
    array([ 24.53566146,  43.76762879,  62.05528877,  79.78986366,
            97.06749311, 113.20798898]))
```

When I tried to plot the half-width maximum, I end up with a plot like the one below

[image]

what I want is a plot with the half-width maximum highlighted in this graph:

[image]

My Python code is

```python
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.scatter(peak_pos, height, color = 'r', s = 10, marker = 'D', label = 'maxima')
#ax.hlines(*results_half[1:], color="C2")
ax.legend()
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

I want to incorporate my half-width matching my x and y arrays not by line width with respect to data points.

Comment: Looks like your half-width maximum is bigger by a factor of `100`. Divide the half-width by `100` (`ax.hlines(*results_half[1:]/2, color="C2")`) and then try to plot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it after understanding the array output from half_width: array[1] is the peak y_half_value, array[2] is X_min in line, array[3] is X_max...I also divided x_min and x_max by 100 to match my x-axis scale...

```
(array([9.78861498, 9.99961288, 9.40256452, 8.3289027 , 6.79530376,
        4.14900022]),
 array([0.395881 , 0.324863 , 0.3012635, 0.283398 , 0.269297 , 0.2587625]),
 array([ 14.74704647,  33.76801591,  52.65272424,  71.46096096,
         90.27218935, 109.05898876]),
 array([ 24.53566146,  43.76762879,  62.05528877,  79.78986366,
         97.06749311, 113.20798898]))
```

So the python script for plotting is

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.scatter(peak_pos, height, color = 'r', s = 10, marker = 'D', label = 'maxima')
ax.hlines(results_half[1], newList[0], newList[1], color="C3")
#ax.scatter(min_pos, min_height*-1, color = 'gold', s = 10, marker = 'X', label = 'minima')
ax.legend()
#ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

The output is:
[image]